# Infer correct typings when converting an array into an object based on a key

Tags: typescript, types

I have an array of items, each with a unique `type` string property. I want to convert this into a type where the type is the key and the value is the original item.

The first thing I do is to ensure I have a correctly typed tuple

```
type MyObject = { type: string; [key: string]: any }

const createObjectList = <T extends ReadonlyArray<MyObject>>(items: T) => items;

const objectList = createObjectList([
  { type: 'a', value: 'foo' },
  { type: 'b', value: 10 },
] as const)

// objectList[0].value is corectly infered as 'foo'
// objectList[1].value is corectly infered as 10
```

After that, I try to convert it into the object type.

```
type ObjectDictionary = {
  [key in typeof objectList[number]['type']]: typeof objectList[number];
}

const typed: ObjectDictionary = undefined as any;
```

The issue here is that, of course, the value is now a union type off all possible values instead of the one specific to that key, so the result is equal to

```
type ObjectDictionary = {
  a: { value: string | number };
  b: { value: string | number };
}
```

instead of

```
type ObjectDictionary = {
  a: { value: string };
  b: { value: number };
}
```

Any idea how to get the individual item type in `ObjectDictionary`?

*node: this isn't the actual code that I am working with; I just tried to simply the core issue*

Comment: I'm confused, your `ObjectDictionary` type is [very different](https://tsplay.dev/wglX0N) from what you've written; it looks like `{a: { readonly type: "a"; readonly value: "foo"; } | { readonly ...`. are you sure this is a [mre]?  This question is easy enough to answer using key remapping, but I need you to clear up the inconsistencies in the question first.

Comment: I think [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NngQqm) might be what you want, but it's not clear to me since your example code doesn't quite agree (e.g., I have  a `{readonly value: 10}` instead of `{value: number}`, and I assume mine is correct and yours is wrong, but if yours is correct then I have to do all kinds of stuff to make things mutable and widened).

Comment: Note that your accepted answer is producing something very much like mine above, so I guess you do want `{readonly value: 10}` and not `{value: number}`.  Would you mind [edit]ing the question so that your versions of actual and expected `ObjectDictionary` types match reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a union is of course because you are using `typeof objectList[number]` as the type of the property, here is no relation to `type`.

If you are using an older version of TS you can use `Extract` to get only the item type that as the same type as the current key. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKBvKokAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FANoDWEIJ519AuiQEMaIKAF8AUOLQB7GuShoKEAcAhJUGADJV5OADwAVKBAAeqmgBNSUAErKLsgDYgAghQoCQeuOvTAAfP4AFFSqALakJAYAlNj+UKEQEQySMnKY0ih+2roKSipqWVo6wEHM4lB4BOAQJADkAnUANFAAbgKOAK61UHUAZtLSdWJNFVWEPXWIzW0d3SQAjAAMI+K8UALWaeTRkhNQvhgAIlQYVLICFCI4uGPMBgDSHAk01ZDSfVCZGsA5wMw0TphRAQCi8Zh1CZ1Xj8A5hUJ6ACiZg8GD0Ew+XyKvxKAKBILBLXwbx6j2eon8LUhNX8dX8KQkUlk8gmFhIh2AJzOFyu2CgnUsED6tAgFg21iEIBSQA)

You can also use the `as` clause in mapped types (since TS 4.1, [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)) to map over the union of item type in the array. As the key you can select the `type` in the `as` clause and then you have the corresponding item type in the mapping type parameter:

```
type MyObject = { type: string; [key: string]: any }

const createObjectList = <T extends ReadonlyArray<MyObject>>(items: T) => items;

const objectList = createObjectList([
  { type: 'a', value: 'foo' },
  { type: 'b', value: 10 },
] as const)

type ObjectDictionary = {
  [TItem in typeof objectList[number] as item['type']]: Omit<TItem, 'type>'>;
}

const typed: ObjectDictionary = undefined as any;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKBvKokAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FANoDWEIJ519AuiQEMaIKAF8AUOLQB7GuShoKEAcAhJUGADJV5OADwAVKBAAeqmgBNSUAErKLsgDYgAghQoCQeuOvTAAfP4AFFSqALakJAYAlNj+UKEQEQySMnKY0ih+2roKSipqWVo6wEHM4lB4BOAQJADkAnUANFAAbgKOAK61UHUAZtLSdWJNFVWEPXWIzW0d3SQAjAAMI+K8UALWaeTRkhNQvhgAIlQYVLICFCI4uGPMBgCS4Qk01ZDSfVCZGsA5wMw0TphRAQCjrTZQR7hZh1CZ1Xj8A5hUKGJ5JFqwmr+Or+FISKSyeQTCwkQ7AE5nC5XbBQTqWCB9WgQCwbaxCEApIA)

Comment: Wait, you're using lowercase type parameters now?  `item` instead of `Item` or `T`?  

Comment: @jcalz Wops .. I just adapted to the convention in the  question .. I'm a convention chameleon 

Comment: Matching the convention of the question is reasonable in theory, but I feel like people who write `{[key in keyof Foo]: ...` are getting confused between index signatures and mapped types.  Either they don't realize that "`key`" is a type parameter and think it's a dummy key name as in `{[key: string]: ...}`, or they don't realize that there is a naming convention that distinguishes between dummy key names and type parameters because the syntaxes for index signatures and mapped types are so similar. Either way I usually try to note that I'm changing from `key` to `K` and why.

Comment: @jcalz - second for me, know the difference, but not the correct convention :)

@TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks, work like a charm (after changing `item` to `TItem` like in the playground link). Had been playing around with the `as`  keyword for quite some time now, almost making it work, but not quite :)